Send group notice replies to separate group, not Reply All
We have a Google group posting listserv and a separate Google group discussion listserv.
All members can use both groups. We need to prevent replies to the posting group and instead reroute them to the discussion group.
Does a "Reply-to" setting exist in the posting group that enables us to route any replies only to the discussion group?
Alternatively, is there a way (e.g., script) to set the posting group's "Reply All" to send replies only to the discussion group?
Thanks in advance for all direction.
